# convert text to number in ms access 2010 select statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to run a query on a massive (650 MB) data table in MS Access 2010.  All the data types for the fields are text, but some fields contain all numbers, even though the data type is text.  I therefore have to convert from text to long int in order to select, for example, all the records who have a value greater than 10 in a specified field.  But whenever I do this, I get a type mismatch error, presumably due to the comparison of a numerical value of a text field.  Here is the SQL for the query which should select from fields that are all of the text data type.

```
SELECT [Organization legal name], [Number of Group Practice members], City, State  
FROM massivetable  
WHERE Clng([Number of Group Practice members])>10  
AND State='CT';
```

I have tried to convert the datatype of the field to long integer in design view, but the operation fails with a message saying there is not enough memory to perform the operation.

Can anyone show me how to fix the code above so that it selects all the records while values greater than 10, without throwing a type conversion error?

Comment: You may have to export all the data, get the database setup properly (either edit the existing database after removing all the previously exported data OR Create a NEW copy of the database) then import the data into the database to get everything back in place.  I had to do it once before on a project and it saved the day.  size of your database is larger than what I was working with though.  good luck.

Comment: @tamak Do you have any solution to my next question?  I am trying to shrink the table with a WHERE clause and INSERT INTO.  Here is the link to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850911/insert-into-query-without-listing-destination-fields-explicitly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use IsNumeric function:

```
SELECT [Organization legal name], [Number of Group Practice members], City, State  
FROM massivetable  
WHERE Iif(IsNumeric([Number of Group Practice members]), Clng([Number of Group Practice members]), 0) >10  
AND State='CT';
```

Comment: Do you have any solution to my next question?  You can read it at this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850911/insert-into-query-without-listing-destination-fields-explicitly