# insert into query without listing destination fields explicitly

Tags: sql, ms-access

In an MS Access 2010 database, I have a massive table that I need to shrink in order to make it usable.  I am only interested in a subset of the records in the table, so I want to select all the data that I care about and insert it into another table that has all the same identical fields.  The problem is that the table has MANY fields and it would be error-prone to list them all explicitly.  Is there some way to simply select all fields and insert into all fields without listing each field explicitly?  If so, how do I change the following code in order to accomplish this?

INSERT INTO massivetable_destination (*)
SELECT * FROM massivetable_source
WHERE State='MS';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding you, but if the tables are in the same access database, it seems you could do the following steps and let the IDE do all of the heavy lifting for you.

1. Right click your massive table and select copy.
2. Right click in the object explorer area and select paste.
3. Optional - rename the copied table.
4. Run a delete query on the copied table, removing all records that you do not want.  The delete query would look like the following:

Query Text

```
DELETE *
FROM MyCopiedTable
WHERE State <> 'ms';
```

Comment: OK. So how do I write the delete query so that it eliminates every record where State does not equal 'MS'?

Comment: @CodeMed - I placed a snippet in my answer

Comment: @CodeMed - cool, glad it worked for you.  As a side note from when I have done Access dev, depending on how much data is in those tables, you may consider doing a compact and repair to shrink the file size.  Completely optional however.